# PHP: Can I call a function after every 30 days

Tags: php, function

I have a function. I need to call that function every **30** days*

How to count time and call a function

**Is PHP is working when there are no one online** ?

Comment: Welcome. Does something not work? Can you post your code? What are you having trouble with, sending a mail? The "automatically" part? Getting a specific person to send to?

Comment: Please check cronjob (linux OS) or scheduler (windows OS)

Comment: Sorry, I just want  to know Is php is working when there are a no one online. That is what I meant by automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can send an email via PHP using the [mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. This is its description:

```
 mail(
    string $to,
    string $subject,
    string $message,
    array|string $additional_headers = [],
    string $additional_params = ""
): bool
```

Taken from the documentation. Let's assume that you implement a PHP file that successfully sends the email. Now all you have to do is to schedule the execution of that file. In Linux you can do it using crontab:

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/run-php-scripts-from-cron-jobs

Your cron job will need to run something like:

```
php sendemail.php
```